# What is the most accurate English translation of 'Stromkern'?

Tags: translation

There's a band called [Stromkern](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromkern), actually from the US but strongly associated with the German alternative scene.

I've been puzzling over what the name actually translates into as both 'strom' and 'kern' seem to have a lot of context-sensitive meanings.

Comment: If you happen to tell us the German meaning ... Wasser hat keine Balken und Strom keinen Kern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seeing how *Stromkern* is making (partially) Electro music, the literal translation "Power Core" seems obvious.

While almost any word has context-sensitive meanings, I wouldn't say either *Strom* or *Kern* is highly context-sensitive, they both have a well-understood and invariant basic meaning.

*Strom* is always something that's somehow flowing rapidly or with great force, like electrical power, a large river, or a mass of people.

*Kern* is always the center/most important part of something that can be differentiated from the rest, be it a physical object (like "the inner core of the Earth") or something immaterial (the core statement of this text is...).

I would say that both *Strom* and *Kern* need context to give them their final meaning, but their general meaning, the idea that they are transporting, is quite fixed on their own.

Comment: "I would say that both Strom and Kern need context to give them their final meaning". That was nice. It remembers me why I like English and German languages. Spanish is not that flexible though. We do the jogging elsewhere :D.